# How do I match a .log but not .log* in regex or python?

Tags: python, regex, string-matching

I am having trouble with regular expressions.

I have:

```
urls = re.findall(r'href=[\'"]?([^\'" >]+)', line)
print urls
```

which gives me:

```
['production_r1499.log']
['production_r1499.log-20140323']
['production_r1499.log-20140323.gz']
```

I am only interested in the .log file. How do I get the regex to only match this one?

alternatively.
Could some approach similar to this work?

```
if str(urls).endswith('.log'):
```

Happy and grateful for suggestions!

Comment: What is the value of `line` variable? Is it an html string?

Comment: It would help to see the input string

Comment: Hard to say without seeing the input, but have you tried using `$`, which is an anchor that matches the end of the string?

Comment: `(?!['])[\w]+.(log)(?<![-'])` will match the log file portion of those samples. Grabs a string followed by .log that's got a ' before and either ' or - after.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
urls = re.findall(r'href=[\'"]?([^\'" >]+\.log)', line)
```

Strictly speaking, this should be anchored to the end of the href attribute. If you are concerned about false positives, maybe add something like `[\'">]` before the closing quote.

Answer (score 0):

Use lookahead to see whether there are any `"`, `'`, `>` or `space` after the `.log` in your match.

```
urls = re.findall(r'href=[\'"]?([^\'" >]+\.log)(?=[\'"> ])', line)
```

Comment: A lookahead doesn't add anything over simply matching the ending delimiter.

Comment: @tripleee if i do not put lookahead then the regex will pick `x.log` as well as `x.log.201`. But OP wanted to pick only the `x.log` and ignore others which have text after the `.log`

Comment: Yes but `a(b)(?:=c)` is better written `a(b)c` if you want just the captured expression. Using a lookahead for `c` is just obscure.

Comment: @tripleee got it what you mean. yes you are right. lol, now i started thinking why i used lookahead :-/

Comment: Thank you for the replies! This works, but I also understand that I can do without lookahead.